# Flutter using two change notifiers on runapp

Tags: flutter, program-entry-point

I have this change notifier :

```
runApp(
  ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthService>(
    child: MyApp(),
    create: (BuildContext context) {
      return AuthService();
    },
  ),
);
```

But i also need to add a new one :

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (_) => ThemeProvider(isLightTheme: true),
    child: MyApp(),
);
```

How would i do this since runapp doesnt seem to allow this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest providers or use `MultiProvider`:

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (_) => AuthService(),
  child: ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (_) => ThemeProvider(),
    child: MyApp(),
  ),
)
```

or:

```dart
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AuthService()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => ThemeProvider()),
  ],
  child: MyApp(),
)
```